# cd ~ Throws error while PWD is in Regisrty

Tags: powershell

CD ~ is Throwing below error .

```
PS HKLM:\> cd ~
cd : Home location for this provider is not set. To set the home location,     call "(get-psprovider 'Registry').Home = 'path'".
At line:1 char:1
+ cd ~
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-Location], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Why is it So ?

Answer (score 1):

This error gets thrown because you are in the registry and by default it doesn't have a home directory. The error message explicitly says that in order to set a home directory (even though I see no reason to) you need to call `(get-psprovider 'Registry').Home = 'path'`

Answer (score 0):

It is So because there is no Home location Assigned for Registry Provider in PowerShell .

By default in PowerShell we have Home Location for Filesystem and will be the Home directory of the loaded user profile.

```
PS C:\> Get-PSProvider -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object home

Home
----
C:\Users\Admin
```

Whereas for Registry Provider, Home location is empty

```
PS C:\> Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Registry | Select-Object home

Home
----
```

But you can set it ,

```
PS C:\> Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Registry | Get-Member


TypeName: System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo

Name             MemberType Definition
----             ---------- ----------
Equals           Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode      Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType          Method     type GetType()
ToString         Method     string ToString()
Capabilities     Property       System.Management.Automation.Provider.ProviderCapabilities Capabilities {get;}
Description      Property   string Description {get;set;}
Drives           Property   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection    [System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo] Drives {get;}
HelpFile         Property   string HelpFile {get;}
Home             Property   string Home {get;set;} # **Can Be SET** .
ImplementingType Property   type ImplementingType {get;}
Module           Property   psmoduleinfo Module {get;}
ModuleName       Property   string ModuleName {get;}
Name             Property   string Name {get;}
PSSnapIn         Property   System.Management.Automation.PSSnapInInfo     PSSnapIn {get;}
```

You can set it like this .

```
PS C:\> $provider = Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Registry
PS C:\> $provider.Home = "HKLM:\"
PS C:\> Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Registry | Select-Object home

Home
----
HKLM:\

PS C:\> cd HKLM:\SOFTWARE\
PS HKLM:\SOFTWARE\> cd ~
PS HKLM:\>
```

Best Regards,

kvprasoon